# How can I remove "None" at the end of my function's return print statement?

Tags: python, function, class

Could someone explain why and how I am receiving "None" at the end of my functions return statement, and how I can remove it? I'm not seeing how a print statement could trigger that in any way to appear.

```
class City:
    # Task 1
    def __init__ (self, name, label, lat, lon, pop_dict):
        self.name = name
        self.label = label
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
        self.pop_dict = pop_dict
    def printPopChange(self, year1, year2): 
        pop_dict = self.pop_dict #pop_dict[year1]
        year1pop = pop_dict[year1]
        year2pop = pop_dict[year2]
        popchange = float(year2pop) - float(year1pop)
        print "The population difference in", self.name, "from", year1.strip("yr"), "to", year2.strip("yr"), "is", popchange, "million people."
Cities = []

f = open("CityPop.csv","r")
header = f.readline()
header = header.strip().split(",")
for line in f:
    record = line.strip().split(",")
    pop = {}
    for i in range (5, 14):
        pop[header[i]] = record[i]
    newCity = City(name = record[3], label = record[4], lat = record[1], lon = record[2], pop_dict = pop)
    Cities.append(newCity)
```

So for example, if I run: 
`print Cities[0].printPopChange("yr1990", "yr1995")`,

I receive:
`"The population difference in Tokyo from 1990 to 1995 is 1.06 million people."`
"None"`

Comment: what do you mean by `receiving "None"`?

Comment: Try returning the string instead of printing it

Comment: I added an edit with an example of what I mean, but I basically mean that when I call to print the class's function, I get the print statement I want, but I also receive "None" below that statement for some reason.

Comment: That's because `Cities[0].printPopChange("yr1990", "yr1995") == None`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq That seemed to get rid of the "None" statement, but now my returned statement appears as `('The population difference in', 'Tokyo', 'from', '1990', 'to', '1995', 'is', 1.0600000000000023, 'million people.')` instead of a regular sentence that the print statement would display.

Comment: @MikeBiehl That's because you're now returning a tuple! You need to join them into a single string. One way is `' '.join(("The population difference in", "Tokyo", "from", "..."))`

Comment: Though, a simpler alternative is probably to just get rid of the `print` statement that's printing the `None`.

Answer (score 1):

`printPropChange()` prints the message itself and doesn't return anything. Just call the function without using `print`.

```
Cities[0].printPopChange("yr1990", "yr1995")
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `print` at the end of the function with `return`.

Then join all the elements of the returned tuple into a string:

```py
print ''.join(Cities[0].printPopChange("yr1990", "yr1995"))
```